# Entire topiclist row as a link

Tags: javascript, css, phpbb

I'm working now on phpbb3 template, i came out from balmy blond template. 
I made topiclist rows highlight on hover, but i want entire row to be clickable too, so that one can click in the middle of row and go to choosen topic.

Any ideas would be appreciated ;d

Comment: please give some to understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily use javascript:

```
<tr onclick="window.location.href=http://example.com" />
```

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/KVZMb/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery also: http://jsfiddle.net/7vTfk/
If you use jQuery you do not need to edit HTML.